# How to create a multi-series line chart with series for each unique item in 1st column?

Tags: jquery, d3.js

I've checked the various tutorials, and can't find my use case covered.

Here is a subset of my dataset, in the form of CSV:

```
Provider,Service date,Unique patients seen
10800,2007-12-03,1
10800,2008-03-21,9
10800,2008-04-16,3
10800,2008-04-18,6
11451,2008-06-27,24
11451,2008-07-10,1
11451,2008-07-14,31
11451,2008-07-15,6
12980,2008-06-17,24
12980,2008-06-27,14
12980,2008-06-28,24
13907,2008-05-04,23
13907,2008-05-05,20
13907,2008-05-08,6
14618,2008-08-27,27
14618,2008-09-04,21
14618,2008-09-05,20
```

What I would like is for there to be a series for each unique provider, with that series having its X axis as the service date, and Y axis as patients seen.

So far, I've looked at the [multi-series line chart tutorial](http://bl.ocks.org/3884955), but I can't convince it to use the data I have instead of columns as it does now.

Any advice or readings?

tarek : )

Comment: Try using d3.nest to group your data points by provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see a working example at http://jsfiddle.net/YHW6H/1/.

I did the following to coerce your data a bit. You'll want to use `d3.csv` to read in your csv file, but I hard coded the values for the example.

```
// you would use d3.csv('filename.csv', function (data) {...})
// in order to populate the data variable, I'm just hard coding it here

var data = [
    {Provider:'10800', 'Service Date': '2007-12-03', 'Unique patients seen':'1'},
    {Provider:'10800', 'Service Date': '2008-03-21', 'Unique patients seen':'9'},
    {Provider:'10800', 'Service Date': '2008-04-16', 'Unique patients seen':'3'},
    {Provider:'10800', 'Service Date': '2008-04-18', 'Unique patients seen':'6'},
    {Provider:'11451', 'Service Date': '2008-06-27', 'Unique patients seen':'24'},
    {Provider:'11451', 'Service Date': '2008-07-10', 'Unique patients seen':'1'},
    {Provider:'11451', 'Service Date': '2008-07-14', 'Unique patients seen':'31'},
    {Provider:'11451', 'Service Date': '2008-07-15', 'Unique patients seen':'6'},
    {Provider:'12980', 'Service Date': '2008-06-17', 'Unique patients seen':'24'},
    {Provider:'12980', 'Service Date': '2008-06-27', 'Unique patients seen':'14'},
    {Provider:'12980', 'Service Date': '2008-06-28', 'Unique patients seen':'24'},
    {Provider:'13907', 'Service Date': '2008-05-04', 'Unique patients seen':'23'},
    {Provider:'13907', 'Service Date': '2008-05-05', 'Unique patients seen':'20'},
    {Provider:'13907', 'Service Date': '2008-05-08', 'Unique patients seen':'6'},
    {Provider:'14618', 'Service Date': '2008-08-27', 'Unique patients seen':'27'},
    {Provider:'14618', 'Service Date': '2008-09-04', 'Unique patients seen':'21'},
    {Provider:'14618', 'Service Date': '2008-09-05', 'Unique patients seen':'20'}    
];

// first we need to coerce the data into the right formats and make the
// names a little more sane
data = data.map( function (d) { 
    return { 
      provider: +d.Provider,   // the + sign will coerce strings to number values
      date: new Date(d['Service Date']),
      patients: +d['Unique patients seen'] }; 
});   

// then we need to nest the data on Provider since we want to only draw one
// line per provider
data = d3.nest().key(function(d) { return d.provider; }).entries(data);
```

Unfortunately the data you provided wasn't that interesting to graph since the providers didn't really overlap.  Once you get all your data loaded it should look nicer :)

Comment: Thank you! That did it! I'm still having some trouble actually graphing the data, but I think that's a separate problem.

Answer (score 0):

the short answer is to re-process your data into a format that d3 can process.

Apologies for not including an example, but typing code on a mobile is a pig

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete, working example, including the data above. There is a problem with the graph in that different providers do not have different colours. Personally, I'm not sure how to fix that.. Thank you all for your help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.category10();

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.patients); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("https://raw.github.com/gist/3925458/c48eb92a3a8a23bfee762b514a4c1256ff0be10d/gistfile1.txt", function(error, data) {

    data = data.map( function (d) {
        return { 
            provider: +d.Provider,   // the + sign will coerce strings to number values
            date: new Date(d['Service date']),
            patients: +d['Unique patients seen'] }; 
    });

  providers = d3.nest().key(function(d) { return d.provider; }).entries(data);


  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));

  y.domain([
    d3.min(providers, function(c) { return d3.min(c.values, function(v) { return v.patients; }); }),
    d3.max(providers, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(v) { return v.patients; }); })
  ]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Number of patients seen");

  var provider = svg.selectAll(".provider")
      .data(providers)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "provider");

  provider.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
      .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

  provider.append("text")
      .datum(function(d) { return {name: d.name, value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]}; })
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," + y(d.value.patients) + ")"; })
      .attr("x", 3)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.value.provider; });
});

</script>
```

Comment: The example I provided shows how to color the providers with different colors.  You need to set the domain of your color categories and use the correct key when setting the color. See http://jsfiddle.net/YHW6H/1/.